# How to read file from GridFS - MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to read file From MongoDB GridFS. When I query it from Mongo Shell I am able to do it as below:

```
1> db.eval("var settings = new Object();\n" +
                "settings = [\n" +
                "{name:\"ID\", type:\"String\", start:1,stop:11},\n" +
                "{name:\"Latitude\",type:\"Float\",start:13,stop:20 },\n" +
                "{name:\"Longitude\",type:\"Float\",start:22,stop:30 },\n" +
                "{name:\"Elevation\",type:\"Float\",start:32,stop:37},\n" +
                "{name:\"State\",type:\"String\",start:39,stop:40},\n" +
                "{name:\"Name\",type:\"String\",start:42,stop:71},\n" +
                "{name:\"GSNFlag\",type:\"String\",start:73,stop:75},\n" +
                "{name:\"HCNFlag\",type:\"String\",start:77,stop:79},\n" +
                "{name:\"WMOID\",type:\"String\",start:81,stop:85},\n" +
                "{name:\"Country\", type:\"String\", start:1,stop:2}\n" +
                "]\n" +
                "db.mycollection.save(settings); \n" +
                "var settings = db.mycollection.findOne(); \n");
```

Above schema file which will be going to save in mycollection collection.It is working fine.

```
2>db.eval(“  function split(line, definition){
    var result = new Object();
    for (key in definition){
        var column = definition[key];
        if (column.type=="fixed"){
            result[column.name] = column.value;
        } else {
            var s = line.substring(column.start-1,column.stop);
            if (column.type=="Float"){
                result[column.name] =  parseFloat(s);
            } else if (column.type=="Integer"){
                result[column.name] =  parseInt(s);
            } else {
                result[column.name] =  s.trim();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
”);
```

This is split function which will split line on the basis of schema file above.It is also working fine.

```
3>db.eval("function readFile(name,collection,definition){
    var data = cat(name);
    var all = new Array();
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    for(i=1;i<lines.length;i++){
        var result = split(lines[i],definition);
        all.push(result);
    }
    collection.insert(all);
    return all.length;
}
",);
```

When I am running the above code through my java code, it is giving error : **`Reference error cat is not defined near cat(name) .`**

**Update:**

My goal is to read fixed width flatfile stored on gridfs and dump it to to mongodb in form of document and then fire sql command on it. To read file from gridfs and to tore it in form of document, I am using Code 3>.

Can you please provide me alternative of cat command.I guess cat is a mongo native shell command  so its not working here. Please correct me If I am wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Wait a second. Why are you using the eval command here? What is your overall goal? What does this have to do with gridfs?

Comment: @wdberkeley: Please refer Update in Question.